# How do bonus tiles and booty tokens work?

Tags: pantheon

In Pantheon, you represent... the collective interests of a pantheon that's trying to get worshiped. (You score points for getting deities worshiped, but the scoring system isn't picky about which deity gets the praise or which culture does the praising.)

At the beginning of the game, you get Bonus Tiles, which have varying effects: extra movement during the spread-civilization phase, a free random god, a free upgrade to an offering tile, etc. During the game, you can pick up Booty Tokens that have similar effects to the Bonus Tiles. The rules, unfortunately, are quite sparse on what to do with the tiles and tokens. (The rules are also poorly copy-edited.) **When can you use the tiles: are they only usable immediately, or can you keep them until some useful moment later and use them then?** Does the "Bonus Movement" tile grant you bonus moves every time you do the Movement step, or is it usable only once and then it's gone?

Some of the bonus tiles are *much* better than others; here's a quick overview.

> **Bonus Movement:** if usable once, has the effect of *half a card.* If usable repeatedly, is equivalent to one of the less powerful gods. (But there's a booty token that has *two* bonus movement, which could well be over-powered if it's usable repeatedly.)
>
> **Random God:** In perfect circumstances, worth 13 victory points. On average, worth one victory point plus some continuing bonus that will last throughout the game.
>
> **Upgrade a Sacrifice Tile:** If you're required to use this immediately after the game starts, it's worth 1 gold coin plus part of one buy action. If you can hold it for later (upgrading a sacrifice tile from 3 to 4), then it can be worth up to 4 gold coins plus the part of a buy action to do the upgrade.
>
> **Place a Column anywhere:** Depends on whether you're trying to win via placing columns or not; worth between 2 and 8 victory points.

Since the effect of the bonus tiles varies greatly depending on when and how you can use them, I really do want to know exactly how they're supposed to be used.

(Side note: I'm talking about the Pantheon game [published in 2011 by Hans im Gluck and Rio Grande](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/94480/pantheon), not any of the other games that happen to be called Pantheon.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having now looked over two [different](http://riograndegames.com/games.html?id=391) English [translations](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/66080/pantheon-english-rules), I'm better able to figure out some of the ambiguous wording.

Bonus Tiles have the same coloring system as gods: gold backgrounds mean "play immediately, then discard," and blue backgrounds mean "keep."

**All bonus tiles are revealed immediately after the first Prepare-Civilization phase, and all gold tiles are immediately executed and discarded.** (If you got the God bonus tile, and it's one of those gods that give you a bonus every turn, you *don't* get that bonus this turn; using that tile happens *after* the phase in civilization-preparation where you'd get the bonus in the first turn.)

**The "Movement" Bonus Tile is kept permanently, and gives +1 Move on every movement action.** (You're not required to use it each Movement action, though.) This can add up to a quite decent bonus over the course of the game.

This means that the single-most-useless tile is the one that upgrades a sacrifice tile, because you're required to use it immediately, and you can only use it to buy a Level 1 tile. This makes it worth one-gold-plus-the-buy-action-to-acquire-it, which isn't particularly useful because you're allowed to do *many* things during a normal buy action.